# WPF MVVM I want to bring data from another Window ViewModel and use it

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm creating a customer care program using WPF MVVM pattern
I created a registration window and a customer information window
I want to bring the value of the data grid of the customer information window to the text box of the creation window

This is information ViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
   private MemberInfo selectedCustomer = new MemberInfo();
      
   public MemberInfo SelectedCustomer
  {
      get => selectedCustomer;
      set
      {   
          SetProperty(ref selectedCustomer, value);

          RegisterViewModel RV = new RegisterViewModel();

          if (value != null)
          {
              RV.Name = selectedCustomer.Name;
           }
        }
    }
 }
```

This is Creat ViewModel

```
 public class RegisterViewModel : ObservableObject
 {
     private string name = "";
     public string Name
     {
         get => this.name;
         set => SetProperty(ref this.name, value);
      }
  }
```

If I use it like this, the value goes over only set, and there is no value to execute the get

Answer (score 1):

> If I use it like this, the value goes over only set, and there is no
> value to execute the get

Not entirely sure I understood this correctly, but you could pass a `MemberInfo` object to the constructor of the `RegisterViewModel` and expose it to the view via a read-only property.

So, the `RegisterViewModel` becomes:

```
public class RegisterViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public RegisterViewModel(MemberInfo member)
    {
         Member = member;
    }

    public MemberInfo Member { get; }
 }
```

Thus in the `MainViewModel`:

```
public MemberInfo SelectedCustomer
{
    get => selectedCustomer;
    set
    {   
         SetProperty(ref selectedCustomer, value);
         RegisterViewModel RV = new RegisterViewModel(selectedCustomer);
     }
}
```

The view then binds to:

```
Text = "{Binding Path=Member.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

---

**Edit**

Since the `RegisterViewModel` is expecting a `MemberInfo` object, you cannot register it and simply call the `GetService<T>` method.

What I usually do in this case, I make use of the [ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities.createinstance?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ActivatorUtilities_CreateInstance_System_IServiceProvider_System_Type_System_Object___) which is part of the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` package.

Through an extension method:

```
public static T Create<T>(this IServiceProvider provider, params object[] args) where T : class
{
    return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<T>(provider, args);
}
```

Which can then be called:

```
this.DataContext = App.Current.Services.Create<RegisterViewModel>(member);
```

This way, if the `RegisterViewModel` is expecting additional registered services through the constructor, those will be resolved by the container.

Comment: Thank you for the information. But I'm using service 
this.DataContext = App.Current.Services.GetService<RegisterViewModel> (); 
like this.
so I have this error 
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'MemversMVVM.Models.MemberInfo' while attempting to activate 'MemversMVVM.ViewModels.RegisterViewModel'.'

Comment: See edit above. This is an important piece of information that should be included in your original question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
I created an event and solved the problem
It's similar to the way you explained it this comment